# Something wrong with this for-loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, d3.js

I got an Array `p` which stores nodes. In the code below, it is possible to set the style of the links and it works totally right. It checks the source property of all links `(d.source)` and all target property `(d.target)` and compares it to the elements p[0] and p[1].

```
link.style("stroke-width", function(d) {
  return p[0] == d.source && p[1] == d.target ? "111px" : "1px";
});
```

Now, i want not to only compare with p[0] and p[1]. I want to go through the complete array p. So i set up this for loop below and compare to p[i] and p[i+1]. But unfortunally it does not work. Can someone maybe give me a hint?

```
for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
  link.style("stroke-width", function(d) {
    return p[i] == d.source && p[i+1] == d.target ? "111px" : "1px";    
  }) 
}
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Did you get an error? Most likely, when you are on the last element in the array, `p[i+1]` is attempting to get an index that is one higher than exists. You'll have to check for `i === p.length-1` before accessing that.

Comment: no, my program d3 does not renders the graphic. what do you mean with `i === p.length-1`? the condition in the loop when to stop?

Comment: `i+1` exceeds the last index in the array when handling the last index.

Comment: Also, don't make `i` a global. Use `var i`.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Have you listened to the instructions given in the comments?

Comment: Like this?

     `link.style("stroke-width", function(d) {
      return p.slice(0, p.length -1).filter((el, i) => d.source === p[i] && d.target === p[i + 1]).length ? '111px' : '1px'
     })`

Comment: Thanks to you all. Unfortunally i did not work. I tried this: `for (i = 0; i < p.length-1; i++) {
  link.style("stroke-width", function(d) {
    return p[i] == d.source && p[i+1] == d.target ? "111px" : "1px";    
  }) 
}` But unfortunall it only renders the last link. Does anyone of you know how to modify my newest loop to make the program renders all and not only the last link?

Comment: At this point the only way to help you is if you create a [MCVE].